# Invalid location of GroupBox with FlowLayoutPanel inside

Tags: winforms, autosize, groupbox, flowlayoutpanel

I have such form layout

```
 Panel Dock=Fill
 GroupBox Dock=Bottom
  FlowLayoutPanel
    Panel
    Panel
    Panel
    Panel
  Panel
  Panel
```

(as shown here https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8664902FAE855051!64006&authkey=!AAy9OiMaSwqs2Fs&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.png)

When I resize the window the layout of 4 Panels inside FlowLayoutPanel is changed incorrectly - last Panel is placed out of GroupBox (https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8664902FAE855051!64005&authkey=!ANnpm-6d3RAKa_M&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.png)
It seems that GroupBox has invalid value of Location.

But if I resize the GroupBox once more, everything is ok and all Controls are placed inside the GroupBox

AutoSize properties of GroupBox, FlowLayoutPanel and all Panels are set to true.

Could anybody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you think the layout is incorrect.  The GroupBox is simply too small to give the FLP enough space to show all the controls.  So of course you see only the top of one of them.  Set the FLP's AutoScroll property to True.  Layouts that have AutoSize controls can be bi-stable, flip-flopping between two layout solutions.

Comment: I've edited the question. I've forget to specify one more control on the form and docking of them. So I expect that when GroupBox resizes it will be moved up. Scrolling isn't acceptable in my situation. Futhermore when I resize the window the second time, layout is correct like here https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8664902FAE855051!64004&authkey=!AMTrJIBb3uSFp1o&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.png